# Camera not working after going back from another Activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, vuforia

I'm working for few weeks with Vuforia,unity and Android in one package and i a bit stuck on one problem. I manage to almost finish all parts of my application besides one.

Because i run some videos, I had to implement another activities besides main camera one, to show them there. I manage to start video, and everything is working like charm up to point when i'm getting back to main camera activity, problem is - camera is black and object is not visibile. I tried to resume or restart whole window again using resume methods and getting focus request on unityPlayer no luck though.

One thing which is even more confusing for me is, clicking app stac in android (icon which is showing all runing apps), and getting back from there is making camera work again, same thing with clicking home button.

Any ideas how i can make camera work after activity is resumed?

Marek

edit: I notice that turning of screen works too.

Comment: please don't duplicate tags in the title, it's sufficient to add them to the tags list